# simple ajax chatting

Tags: php, html, ajax, chat

I want to make an very simple chatting page

no login required
no sql going to be used

Only php, html and ajax is needed.

First, I made a

`chat.html`:

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">
function chat()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","chatreturn.php?name=getElementById("name").value&data=getElementById("data").value",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


</script>


</head>
<body>

<form>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
writing: <input type="text" id="data" />
<button onclick=chat() >
</form>
<div id=chat></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `chatreturn.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$logger = fopen("chatlog.txt","w");
$msg = $_GET["name"];
$msg += " " + $_GET["data"];
fwrite($logger,$msg);
fclose($logger);

$logdata = fopen("chatlog.txt","r");

$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
$display += fgets($logdata);
document.write($display);
fclose($logdata );
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect everytime I send a message, the message is added to current document but the weird symtom is that it returns nothing.

Comment: what is up with all those `fgets($logdata);`??

Comment: You seem to mix PHP and Javascript. For example `$display += fgets($logdata);` should be `$display .= fgets($logdata);` and `document.write($display);` should be `echo $display;`. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning how to write a chat program is nice, but my advice is that you need first to use the right tools for the job.

While it is nice to learn how to bake an apple pie, you don't need to also grow an apple tree along with it.

1. Use libraries to help you make things more concise, and focus on what's really important about your project, and not the nuts and bolt around it. For example, [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for your XHR would be a good start.
2. Javascript debuggers are a must when dealing with XHRs. I suggest Chrome with the developer tools. I personally don't think any other tool can beat it in terms of features and usefulness.
3. Use a database to store your data. Files are not a good idea.
4. There are **good** examples from the PHP manual; learn from them.
5. You seem to not entirely grasp the PHP syntax, and mix server side and client side code (also, you are writing Javascript code inside your GET url? you should have Javascript errors since your quotes are not even escaped). Since a chat program *requires* a good understanding of them two, start with some basic tests first.